# Orientation of hyperplanes given linear system with rank-deficient matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If you are given a linear system that has a rank-deficient coefficient matrix how will the hyper planes of the given matrix rows orient themselves in space?

My thinking through of the question:
Since it is a rank-deficient matrix, does it mean the rows of the matrix are linearly dependent and there is no unique solution. Since there is no unique solution the planes would then be parallel and since they are linearly dependent does that mean they are all the same plane.

Comment: You’re confusing no solution with an infinite number of them. Two non-parallel planes in $\mathbb R^3$ intersect in a line that is the infinite set of solutions to the system of two equations represented by the planes.

Comment: But given hyperplanes described by the rows of a rank deficient matrix of a linear system give you parallel planes and thus no intersection at all?

Comment: $\tiny{\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix}}$ is rank-deficient, but no two of the three planes are parallel.